# WT12 module in SPP profile

Tags: bluetooth, uart

I am a newbie and trying to work out the way to a simple application I have to finish. What I want my Bluegiga WT12 module to do is, just enter to the SPP profile and wait for any initiators and get connected. Then start the data from UART to flow over Bluetooth to the other device. That should be very easy, but I could not find my way in the user guides.

What settings do I need to send via iWRAP commands for my goal?

Comment: A bit more detail please. What have you tried so far? What computer or microcontroller are you using this with? Have you looked for libraries with demo code? For example, a quick search of Bluegiga WT12 Arduino library turned up some hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the default operation mode of iWrap:

- SPP profile is enabled
- The module will jump into what is called "data mode" when a connection is opened and seamlessly transfer the data from the Bluetooth connection to the UART port.

In case you have messed up your configuration, you can issue "set reset" to return the factory settings (Available at least since iWrap 4).